# how to dynamically get datasource in crystal reports from xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, vb6, crystal-reports

I have a report whose datasource is sql server.I want the report to be able to pick different database dynamically so that if I call it using vb app it can pick a database.I was thinking database and password being got from xml document.
Please help other methods are welcome.Thanks.

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ("C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\working\EMPLOYEES.rpt")
    CrystalReportViewer1.Show()
End Sub
```

my vb code that calls the report above.

Comment: solution (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7345fc6c-9749-42a3-b866-509c57f3cc35/changing-crystal-reports-connection-string-dynamically?forum=vscrystalreports)(http://www.simplevb.net/content/read-data-from-an-xml-file-in-vbnet-ID42.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution`Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
    Me.Left = 0
    Me.Top = 0
    Me.Height = 10000
    Me.Width = 18408

End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim crReportDocument As New ReportDocument()
    Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim CrTable As Table
    'Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\About2Go_H.A.M\working\db.xml")
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\Users\Martin\Desktop\About2Go_H.A.M\working\db.xml")
    Dim title = From t In document.Descendants("ServerName") Select t.Value
    Dim ServerName1 = title.First()
    Dim title2 = From t In document.Descendants("DatabaseName") Select t.Value
    Dim DatabaseName1 = title2.First()
    Dim title3 = From t In document.Descendants("UserID") Select t.Value
    Dim UserID1 = title3.First()
    Dim title4 = From t In document.Descendants("Password") Select t.Value
    Dim password1 = title4.First()
    crReportDocument.Load("C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\About2Go_H.A.M\working\EMPLOYEES2.rpt")
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument
    CrTables = crReportDocument.Database.Tables

    Dim crLoc As String
    crLoc = UserID1 & ".dbo"

    For Each CrTable In CrTables

        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        'Read MachineName\InstanceName,Database details from User interface
        'and load them into crConnectionInfo object
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ServerName1
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = DatabaseName1
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = UserID1
        crConnectionInfo.Password = password1
        crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
        CrTable.Location.Substring(CrTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)

    Next

    crReportDocument.ReportOptions.EnableSaveDataWithReport = False
    'Refresh the ReportViewer Object
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    'Bind the ReportDocument to ReportViewer Object
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument
End Sub
```

End Class`